# Is it possible to prevent editing of the address bar in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, permissions, modern-experience, modern-team-site

I’m creating SharePoint Online ModernUI team site.

I don't want the user to paste the URL directly in web blowser, so I want to prohibit editing the address bar.

Is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want the user to paste the URL directly"? What exactly you want to achieve by prohibiting editing the address bar?

Comment: The URL is displayed in the address bar of the web browser. If user edit it, they can change the screen without button operation, so I want to prohibit it.

Comment: You cannot prohibit users from changing the address bar of the web browser. If you have confidential information and you don't want your users to access the screen then you can handle that at screen/page level. maybe doing some permissions management for that screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I have to handle permission at some target page. I understood. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prohibit users from changing the address bar of the web browser.

If you have confidential information and you don't want your users to access the screen then you can handle that at screen/page level. maybe doing some permissions management for that screen.

**Reference**:
[SharePoint site permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-SharePoint-site-permissions).